# First day last month at specific time (00:01) & Last day of last month at specific time (23:59)

Tags: python, bash, shell, date

So I have written a script in python.

Basically it pulls alot of data. The script takes 40 fiber lines for a company to see the uptime of them. It lists all the names, the downtime in minutes, and the uptime as a percentage.

This gets put in a *.csv* and sent to a contact in the company that uses this to see if the company meets their promised upkeep.

Now I have done the script, and have run it manually, but when I set it up with cron I'm having some issues with the date.

I want the date to go from 00:01 First day of last month, so for example 01. September 00:01 and the end date to be 30th of September 23:59.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions about code, please remember to include a [mcve] so readers can effectively answer the question.

Comment: Are you asking what date formats to input to cron so that they will run the job against the previous month's data? There isn't enough info here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, so I'm writing this to run on the first and last day of every month.
I recommend to use multiple lines, like so:

```
1 0 1 * * /path/to/your/script.py # First day of month
55 23 30 4,6,9,11 * /path/to/your/script.py  # Last day of all months with 30 days
55 23 31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 * /path/to/your/script.py # months with 31 days
55 23 28 2 * /path/to/your/script.py # Last day of February
```